# Kill a running process

Tags: c#, process, orientdb

I would like kill this process but this code isn't work, because the process still work.

My code:

```
ProcessStartInfo processInfoOrient = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
    FileName = @"B:\db\orientdb-3.0.29\bin\server.bat",
    UseShellExecute = true,
    CreateNoWindow = false,
    WorkingDirectory = @"B:\db\orientdb-3.0.29\bin"
};

Process processOrient = new Process();
processOrient.StartInfo = processInfoOrient;
processOrient.Start(); //works fine
//work
//work
processOrient.Kill(); //this not working, window (cmd) isn't close and process works. I don't get any of errors.
```

Comment: Please share with us the contents of `server.bat`.

Answer (score 0):

We had to kill the Java process after OrientDB process and works fine :)
Sample code:

```
prc.Kill();
Process[] prcJava;
prcJava = Process.GetProcessesByName("java");
prcJava[0].Kill();
```